Reference Request: Definition on parity of scalar-valued multivariate functions (even or odd)
I am studying the densities of multivariate Gaussian distributions and I am curious about the parity of those scalar-valued multivariate functions.
For a function $f(\mathbf{x}): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, I found a Wikipedia page that defines its parity as:

Even symmetric if $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(-\mathbf{x})$ for any $\mathbf{x}$
Odd symmetric if $f(\mathbf{x}) = -f(\mathbf{x})$ for any $\mathbf{x}$

However, the Wikipedia page does not list any formal references related to this definition. Can anyone suggest any formal references, such as textbooks or articles, that discuss the definitions and properties of these scalar-valued multivariate functions? I have checked the usual undergraduate calculus books but did not find related discussions except for the univariate case.
Thank you! The Wikipedia page I found is:
Wikipedia: Even and Odd Functions
